# Flutter face unlock from stored photo in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, face-recognition

In flutter is there any way to make face unlock?
I will save some faces in firebase, when the user starts the app it would check whether his face matches to any of those some faces. If matches then the app starts

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/face-detection-in-flutter-using-firebases-ml-kit-57a7a9078c3f) and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymyYUCrJnxU)

Using the [Firebase ML Vision package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision#-installing-tab-), you can do exactly what you want.

First of all, select an image, either from the gallery or camera using any image picker plugin of your choice.

```
var awaitImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
imageFile = await awaitImage.readAsBytes();
imageFile = await decodeImageFromList(imageFile);
setState(() {
imageFile = imageFile;
pickedImage = awaitImage;
});
```

Then create a `FirebaseVisionImage`

```
FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(pickedImage);
```

Then create an instance of FaceDetector:

```
final FaceDetector faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector();
```

To test it, find out if an image was detected from the FaceDetector:

`final List<Face> faces = await faceDetector.processImage(visionImage);`

If you want to check if the face is the same as the one on Firebase, you can try comparing results from the Face object such as contours.